# How to determine the display order of <li> in a list with 4 columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a `dropdown` menu (country List by continent) in `4 columns`. What I'm looking for is the answer of how to determine the order of the countries. The order should be something like this:

Example 1:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4
   A          B         C         D
```

Example 2:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4 
    A         C         D         E
    B`
```

Example 3:

```
 Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4   
   A          C         E        G    
   B          D         F
```

The idea is to use all columns equally but keep the alphabetical order from the top to the bottom of each column. I'm looking for a simple solution with CSS / jQuery if possible. How can I do that?

Comment: Please show what have you tried? http://www.jsfiddle.com/ might come in handy.

Comment: Why can you not just hard code it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bit tricky since naive implementations tended to favor earlier columns and leave latter columns underpopulated. This version results in equal distribution of elements between the four columns regardless of number of elements.

The trick is to recalculate the number of items per column when advancing to next column based on number of items remaining.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WvmZ/1/

```
<ul class='menu'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<style type='text/css'>
  .menu { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  .menu > li { 
      display: inline-block; 
      width: 100px; 
      border: 1px solid red; 
      padding: 5px; 
      vertical-align: top; 
  }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
  var idx = 0;
  // iterate on columns
  for (var column = 0; column < 4; ++column) {
      // based on remaining items, recalculate per_column
      var per_column = Math.ceil((data.length - idx) / (4 - column));
      // this_col tracks #items in current column
      for (var this_col = 0; this_col < per_column && idx < data.length; ++this_col) {
          $('<div></div>').html(data[idx]).appendTo($('.menu li').eq(column));
          ++idx;
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts I appreciate it. I tried to implement your code but can't get it right. Could you please have a look and let me know how I might correct it? Please keep in mind that it's suppose to be a dropdown menu. Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/5qsPn/1/

Comment: You had forgotten to choose jQuery library from top left corner (Frameworks & Extensions). Also, you need to only have as many <li> elements as the number of columns you want - one <li> represents one column. There is no need for the empty <a> elements since they are to be populated by Javascript. Please take a look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qsPn/3/

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/5qsPn/4/ for a hover-dropdown variation. Mouse-over 'Americas' to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach which seeks to fill up each column to their max capacities.

*UPDATED CODE SAMPLE TO USE SELECT DROPDOWNS*

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Column 1</p>
            <select id="col1"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Column 2</p>
            <select id="col2"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Column 3</p>
            <select id="col3"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Column 4</p>
            <select id="col4"></select>        
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
    var maxCols = 4;
    var maxItemsPerColumn = Math.ceil(list.length / maxCols);
    var column = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {  
        // For each successive column, we'll want to re-evalutate how many items remain and 
        // determine how to best distribute them amongst the remaining columns.
        var remaining = (list.length - i);
        if (remaining % maxItemsPerColumn == 0 && column != 1) {
            maxItemsPerColumn = Math.ceil(remaining / (maxCols - column));
        }

        // Increment column once we've riched the max fill limit.
        if ( (i > 0) && !(i % maxItemsPerColumn)) {
            column++;
        }

        var targetId = '#col' + (column);
        // With the known column to add to. Use jquery to append option elements to appropriate
        // select element.
        $(targetId).append('<option value=' + list[i] +'>' + list[i] + '</option>');
    }
```

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/Ssy3q/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your Fiddle but I tried it and noticed that it doesn't work the way I would like to have it. When you e.g. increase the numbers up to 13 the numbers are not equally spread and the columns 1-3 are by 4 numbers and column 4 has only the number 13. I'm also not sure of how to implement this to a dropdown menu?http://jsfiddle.net/Teo123/wCg72/1/

Comment: @Teo The logic behind this code is that for X total columns, and Y items in a list.  It will attempt to fill each column as full as they can get before moving on to the next column, while also ensuring that all items exist somewhere within a column.  Here's an updated fiddle with a dropdown example.  http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/Ssy3q/1/

Comment: Thanks again but I think that @Alo Sarv fits more with what I was looking for. +1 for the efforts.